# how to use Gradle build services to find total build time?

Tags: java, gradle

I’m the author of the [build-time-tracker](https://github.com/asarkar/build-time-tracker) plugin that reports build time. It uses build listeners.

Using Configuration Cache along with a plugin that registers build listeners fail with the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Configuration cache problems found in this build.

...
 - Plugin 'com.asarkar.gradle.build-time-tracker': registration of listener on 'Gradle.addListener' is unsupported
```

https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/configuration_cache.html#config_cache:requirements:build_listeners

> Plugins and build scripts must not register any build listeners. That is listeners registered at configuration time that get notified at execution time. For example a BuildListener or a TaskExecutionListener.
>
> These should be replaced by build services

Build services docs:

https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/build_services.html#build_services

> A build service can be used to receive events as tasks are executed. To do this, create and register a build service that implements OperationCompletionListener. Then, you can use the methods on the BuildEventsListenerRegistry service to start receiving events.

It appears [BuildEventsListenerRegistry](https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/javadoc/org/gradle/build/event/BuildEventsListenerRegistry.html) only has a method for task completion from which we can get task execution time, but there are no methods for build initiation and completion. Without a way to find total build time, the plugin can’t start using build services.

There is a [ticket](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/18520) I have opened with Gradle that is just sitting there. As quoted above, the docs make it sound like it build listeners can be easily replaced by build services, but the API doesn’t match up. The ticket also has a minimum, reproducible example.

Anyone know how to use build services to find total build time?

Comment: The deprecation was added in [this](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/19389), but as you've said, there is no clear guidance for a direct replacement. Gradle's own internal stuff still uses the deprecated method. However, your plugin appears to be moreorless the same thing as build scans, so I would look into what the build scan is doing under the hood to capture that information and see if there are any non `internal` APIs being used.

Comment: @FranciscoMateo Build scan is not a plugin, so it doesn't help me. A plugin has to work with several limitations that build scan may or may not have. Furthermore,build scans may or may not use build services.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed: it looks like the Gradle team haven't exposed a new API to do this. There is a [feature request](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/17659) out there, and it's currently marked as due for Gradle 8.1. So stay tuned.

In the meantime, it is possible to find internal Gradle classes where this information is exposed. In particular, there is a `BuildOperationListener` class which can be used to listen for the end of the build.

To this end, I'm currently using the following plugin (written in Kotlin) to do the same job in Gradle 7.6:

```
import java.time.Duration
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import javax.inject.Inject
import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.api.services.BuildService
import org.gradle.api.services.BuildServiceParameters
import org.gradle.internal.build.event.BuildEventListenerRegistryInternal
import org.gradle.internal.operations.BuildOperationCategory
import org.gradle.internal.operations.BuildOperationDescriptor
import org.gradle.internal.operations.BuildOperationListener
import org.gradle.internal.operations.OperationFinishEvent
import org.gradle.internal.operations.OperationIdentifier
import org.gradle.internal.operations.OperationProgressEvent
import org.gradle.internal.operations.OperationStartEvent

class BuildFinishedPlugin @Inject constructor(
    private val buildEvents: BuildEventListenerRegistryInternal
) : Plugin<Project> {

    override fun apply(target: Project) {
        val buildFinishedService = target.gradle.sharedServices.registerIfAbsent("buildFinished", BuildFinishedService::class.java) {
            parameters.buildStartTime = LocalDateTime.now()
        }
        buildEvents.onOperationCompletion(buildFinishedService)
    }

    /**
     * Class needs to be a [BuildService] in order to act as an [BuildOperationListener]
     */
    abstract class BuildFinishedService : BuildService<BuildFinishedService.Parameters>, BuildOperationListener {

        interface Parameters : BuildServiceParameters {
            var buildStartTime: LocalDateTime
        }

        override fun started(buildOperation: BuildOperationDescriptor, startEvent: OperationStartEvent) {}

        override fun progress(operationIdentifier: OperationIdentifier, progressEvent: OperationProgressEvent) {}

        override fun finished(buildOperation: BuildOperationDescriptor, finishEvent: OperationFinishEvent) {
            val category = buildOperation.metadata as? BuildOperationCategory
            if (category == BuildOperationCategory.RUN_MAIN_TASKS)
                buildFinishedAction()
        }

        private fun buildFinishedAction() {
            val timeNow = LocalDateTime.now()
            println("Finished build at ${timeNow.formatAsDate()}")
            println("Build time: ${timeSinceBuildStarted(timeNow).formatAsDuration()}")
        }

        private fun timeSinceBuildStarted(buildFinishTime: LocalDateTime): Duration
            = Duration.between(parameters.buildStartTime, buildFinishTime)

        private fun LocalDateTime.formatAsDate(): String {
            val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm.ss")
            return formatter.format(this)
        }

        private fun Duration.formatAsDuration(): String {
            return when (val minutes = toMinutes()) {
                0L -> "${seconds()}s"
                else -> "$minutes min ${seconds()}s"
            }
        }

        private fun Duration.seconds(): String {
            return String.format("%1.3f", toMillisPart().toDouble() / 1000)
        }

    }

}
```

This [blog post](https://proandroiddev.com/gradle-configuration-caching-replacing-a-build-listener-with-build-services-40bde11937f1) by Jonny Caley goes into further details on this approach (and has arguably a more elegant way of getting the build start time).

Comment: Thanks. I've since resorted to using the oldest task start time as the build start time, but your answer and the linked article seem interesting. I'll take a look.

Comment: I’ve read the blog post. It also uses the start time of the first task, but computes the time for configuration separately. I’m not convinced that I should show configuration time separately or at all.

Comment: The bit I was looking at was the details property in a BuildOperationDescriptor seems to be a RunRootBuildWorkBuildOperationType.Details when the build finishes, which in turn has a buildStartTime property. All getting quite deep into the inner, undocumented workings of Gradle though

Comment: I saw that, but as you said, it's internal and undocumented. I won't be rushing to use it in my plugin because that'll put its users at risk.